# Using Google Map locations and API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working on a multilingual website. Instead of making entries for all website languages  into database all countries, states/regions/, cities, localities (which is huge work) I'd like to use Google map locations and maps. User will register themselves choosing their locations from the autocomplete list, they will post their products to the website showing the location country, cities etc. Users also will be able to make a search products by locations as well was admin will list the users and products by the locations . Google map locations and API is great for this. In whatever language you type the locations it shows. One of the website using  Google map API is airbnb.com, they integrated it very successfully. I see Google offers map API for business but our website will not have much volume like airbnb that we don't need 100 000 requests per day (BTW if we will have 1000 request per day it would be great). Free API is also not for us and doesn't meet our requirements because it is limited and our website will partially be not free (we will charge business owners, not all users). Is there any way to get this issue solved. I appreciate your recommendations. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need Maps For Business if anybody can sign up for your website. btw. It sounds great! Good luck developing,

Comment: Kaskader you are right, at current volume we dont need to purchase Google map license for business. Google provides 25 K call/day for places call, in case excess of this quota we will be charged 0.50 USD/1000 K which helps us to get this issue solved. Thanks for your answer. Best,

Answer (score 1):

If your website is not freely available (to all users) then you must purchase a Maps for Business license.

Comment: But we dont need 100 000 request per day, the price for license google map business is not affordable for us and we will not have such volume. Is there any case that google offers map with reduced request per day? I hope by this way the price for the licence could go down but not 10 000 USD annually.

Comment: I received an email from Google saying this is autocomplete google places API that I can use 100 000 call/day.